# Une nuance entre « c'est le contraire » et « c'est l'inverse »

Tags: expressions

> Mon interlocuteur : X will be easy enough. It’s Y that is difficult to solve.
>
> Moi : Actually, **it’s the other way round**. {Y is easy; X is difficult.}

Comment dit-on « it’s the other way round » dans ce contexte précis en français ?

J'ai hésité entre :

> Moi : En fait, c'est plutôt **le contraire**.
>
> Moi : En fait, c'est plutôt **l'inverse**.

Comment: Both of them are completely correct.

Comment: Pour aller plus loin : 
Contraire : http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/generic/cherche.exe?15;s=2456623845;;
  ----  Inverse:  http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/generic/cherche.exe?15;s=2456623845;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En disant "le contraire", j'imagine la négation de la phrase d'origine.
En disant "l'inverse", j'imagine changer l'ordre des mots dans la phrase.
En général, les deux sont synonymes, mais il y a tout de même une légère nuance.

Donc si je dis :

> Je suis intelligent

On pourra répondre "non, c'est le contraire", mais pas "non, c'est l'inverse", car il n'y a pas d'ordre de mots à changer.

---

Dans la phrase de la question, il y a bien "X" et "Y" à inverser. Il y a en plus "facile" et ""difficile", ce qui permet d'utiliser les deux en gardant la même idée.

L'inverse :

> Y is easy; X is difficult

Le contraire :

> X is not easy, Y is not difficult

Comment: @LUNA Using "c'est le contraire" doesn't sound wrong to me. I guess "inverse" is more specific than "contraire". So there are cases you can't use "inverse", but I don't see cases you can't say "le contraire". In your example, you can find an antonym of "chef", as "On dirait que c'est ton employé" for instance...

Comment: Following the same logic, you could say "l'opposé", but it's not very common. It would mean "it's false that both X is easy and Y is difficult"

Comment: Hi, Random. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/une-nuance-entre-se-m%C3%AAler-de-et-se-m%C3%AAler-%C3%A0 I was planning to make a new question out of this very point that you corrected, actually. What a coincidence! Merci. :) So the correct pronoun that corresponds with "**son** nez {**your/our** nose}" to talk about a **generalised** situation is "**nous** regardent" instead of "**se** regardent"? Also, as to the corresponding subject, is it "**nous**" or "**il**"?

Comment: @LUNA haha, reading my edit comment, I don't know how I could write "doufrait" instead of "voudrait" :D Indeed you pointed out an interesting point: Why "son nez" is correct and "se regardent" must use "nous"... I don't see an easy reason right here, you should make a new question ;)

Comment: @Random Hi. I'm about to create a new question out of this matter. :) By the way, in the following instance, what do you think about using "il/elle" in "il/elle peut compter" to refer to the speaker? Using "locuteur/locutrice" is a bit too much, I guess. Merci.

Comment: @Random http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/lexpression-je-suis-bien-entour%C3%A9e

Comment: @LUNA I'm kind of lost, I didn't understand what you are asking for, and didn't understand what is the connection with the link you mentionned... :S

Comment: @Random Oh, in that post, I said "**elle** peut compter" and "**lui** porter secours" to refer to the speaker of that French sentence. Would you have done the same yourself, and used the pronouns "**elle**" and "**lui**" in this instance, Random? :)

Comment: @LUNA Indeed, "sur qui elle peut compter pour lui porter secours" is very natural (as does the whole question actually)

Answer (score 0):

There are two related words: *réciproque* and *opposé*.

*Réciproque*, can have the meaning of *inverse*, and in philosophy or logic, can also have the following meaning ([CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ciproque)): *Deux propositions hypothétiques sont réciproques quand l'hypothèse de l'une est la conséquence de l'autre, et quand la conséquence de la première est l'hypothèse de la seconde. La définition doit être réciproque (...) Si une figure est un triangle, c'est un polygone de trois côtés; si une figure est un polygone de trois côtés, c'est un triangle (Goblot 1920)*

*Opposé* can have the meaning of *contraire*. [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oppos%C3%A9) gives the following example: _Le beau s'oppose au laid. Les yeux saillants, à fleur de tête, s'opposent aux yeux profondément enfoncés (Richer,Nouv. anat. artist., t.2, 1920, p.123).