# L'expression « je suis bien entouré(e) »

Tags: expressions

> En tout cas, **je suis bien entourée**. Je m'en sortirai.

Cette expression signifie-t-elle qu'il y a des gens (que ce soit au travail, à l'école, entre amis ou en famille) sur qui elle peut compter pour lui porter secours en cas de pépin ?

Cela me laisse perplexe de voir que le verbe « entourée » n'est pas suivi de « de + qqn/qqch ».

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cette expression peut être utilisée dans plusieurs situations :

- Quand on est littéralement bien entouré de plusieurs personnes que l'on apprécie. Lors d'une soirée par exemple, quand on discute avec de bons amis
- Quand, dans la vie en général, on a plusieurs personnes qui nous sont proches et sur lesquelles on peut compter

Cela va dépendre du contexte. On peut compter sur ces personnes en cas de pépin mais aussi d'une façon générale, pour passer de bons moments.

L'absence de « qqn/qqch » après l'expression est tout à fait normale car l'expression « Je suis bien entouré(e) » sous-entend généralement qu'on est bien entouré de personnes. On peut être entouré de quelque chose, mais dans ce cas là il faut souvent préciser pour que cela soit plus clair.

EDIT 
D'un point de vue grammatical, on peut se poser la question du problème posé par l'absence de COD après la structure " être bien entouré ". Mon avis personnel (Et suivant le commentaire de Papa Poule) est que l'omission du COD pour ce verbe transitif est acceptable pour cette expression. À l'oral pas de problème mais à l'écrit je conseille tout de même de rajouter explicitement le COD si le texte se veut soutenu.

Comment: Dans le cadre du travail, je ne dirai pas forcément que ces personnes sont obligatoirement proches. On pourrait se retrouver dans la situation où on demande à quelqu'un une tâche difficile, et qu'il réponde qu'il est bien entouré, dans le sens où il a des gens compétent dans son équipe. Ex: Un investisseur à un patron d'une start-up : Je vais résoudre ce problème, et je peux compter sur l'aide de mes collègues/employés qui sont compétents.

Comment: il n'y a absolument aucun problème grammatical à ne pas préciser de qui ou de quoi on est entouré. De plus, le préciser ne serait pas un COD mais un COI. De manière générale on n'adjoint pas de COD à un verbe à la voie passive.

Answer (score 2):

La question de l'absence de complément d'objet indirect aurait pu se poser si la phrase avait été:

> Je suis entouré.

Tout locuteur natif conviendra qu'une information manque pour que cette phrase soit satisfaisante. Ce n'est pourtant pas le cas avec cette phrase très similaire :

> Je suis encerclé.

Ici, l'affirmation est clairement intelligible car le verbe utilisé sous-entend que ce qui nous encercle réduit notre liberté de mouvement.

Dans la phrase :

> Je suis bien entouré.

la présence de l'adverbe « bien » ajoute une indication similaire qui suffit à rendre là aussi l'affirmation autosuffisante. Elle sous-entend « je suis entouré de personnes (ou d'animaux, voire objets) dont la présence est positive ».

Cette autosuffisance est bien sûr aussi vraie avec l'inverse :

> Je suis mal entouré.

Answer (score 1):

Réponse: Je suis bien entouré [d'amis]. Il n'y a pas le mot **de** puisque la personne ne la pas dit comme cela. Si on veut dire de quoi ou de qui, on met le DE.

Rien n'oblige le locuteur a préciser le DE QUI ou DE QUOI. :)

Answer (score 1):

On a l'*expression* « être bien entouré », pour « **compter au nombre de ses [familiers](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/familier) des gens de bon conseil.** » ([Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/entourer)) et c'est peut-être tout simplement qu'une expression est un peu figée, et ainsi moins tributaire du fait qu'un complément soit requis ou non normalement etc. Le sens de l'expression est complet. Par ailleurs Le TLFi a une entrée pour le participe passé [*entouré*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entour%C3%A9/1) en adjectif « sans complément de moyen ou d'agent; qualifie seulement une personne; correspond à entourer [Être, se tenir autour de./Le sujet désigne un être animé/Le complément d'objet désigne une personne/Avec bienveillance ; II B 1 a] ». C'est construit comme la voix passive mais s'analyse comme un adjectif. Voici quelques citations provenant de l'entrée pour le verbe et pour le participe/adjectif :

> [...]
>   II B (entouré)
>
> - [Aidé, soutenu par ceux qui vivent autour.]
>    *C'est fou ce qu'il
>     est entouré, le cher orphelin!* (Beauvoir)
>
> ---
>
> [...]
>   II B 1 a (entourer)
>
> - [[Avec bienveillance]]
>   *Celui qui s'emportait, le groupe entier
>     l'entourait, l'apaisait, l'obligeait à s'excuser* (Sartre)
>
>   - [Spéc.
>       Tenir compagnie (à quelqu'un).]
>      *Il paraissait, vers la fin de la
>       journée, entouré de sa cour d'admirateurs* (Peyré)
>   - [En particulier
>       Soutenir, aider (quelqu'un).]
>      *Depuis que j'existe, j'ai été
>       entouré, préservé, soutenu, vivifié par les femmes* (Montherlant)
>   - [[Sans complément second.] Entourer quelqu'un. L'aider.]
>      *Dans la
>       solitude il emportait, l'entourant et le soutenant, l'image de la
>       société* (Bergson)
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi, entouré,
>   entourer, extraits choisis, montage ]

Larousse présente aussi le sens « avoir autour de soi des admirateurs, des flatteurs » pour [*être (très) entouré*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_entour%C3%A9/29971?q=entour%C3%A9#29877), en plus d'« être soutenu par l'attention de ses proches ».

---

Mais en question on a *je suis bien entourée*, et c'est à mon avis *aidé/soutenu par ceux qui vivent autour*, et il y a la notion de *s'en sortir* qui cadre parfaitement avec ça. Oui, on comprend bien le sens de l'expression. En contexte on pourrait aussi peut-être dire *plusieurs personnes m'entourent* avec un sens similaire. Mais d'autre part, pour dire de manière ponctuelle *je suis avec, en compagnie de, quelqu'un, mes amis, des gens*, ou *je suis en bonne compagnie*, plutôt qu'encerclé par une cohue docile ou simplement accompagné, je préfère les dire plutôt que de dire *je suis entouré* suivi de ces mêmes compléments...