# Une nuance entre « se mêler de » et « se mêler à »

Tags: expressions

J'imagine que « se mêler de » désigne le fait de fourrer volontairement et indûment son nez dans les affaires d'autrui qui ne nous regardent pas.

> Exemple 1 : Je dirais « Ne vous **en** mêlez pas. »
>
> Mais pas « Ne vous **y** mêlez pas. »

Quant à « se mêler à », s'agit-il plutôt de s'y retrouver impliqué de force, ou en étant poussé par les circonstances ?

> Exemple 2 : Je dirais « Pourquoi est-ce que je me retrouve mêlée **à** ça ? »
>
> Mais pas « Pourquoi est-ce que je me retrouve mêlée **de** ça ? »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le sens premier de "mêler", c'est "mélanger" mais souvent dans le sens de "rapprocher" ou "rendre indissociable". Tous les différents sens sont issus de celui-ci. Par exemple:

> Tu n'aurais pas dû mêler tes parents à cette affaire. Cela ne les concerne pas. -> Tu n'aurais pas dû mettre tes parents au courant de cette affaire.

Ou à la forme pronominale:

> Tenant à rester incognito, il se mêle à la foule. -> Il s'intègre à la foule de manière à ce qu'on ne le remarque pas.

On mêle donc en général quelque chose à autre chose.

Cependant, un autre sens très utilisé existe aussi : "se mêler de X" signifie "s'impliquer dans X" ou "s'intéresser à X", mais avec la notion que X ne concernait pas directement la personne. Il s'agit donc souvent d'un reproche quant au fait que la personne s'occupe de choses qui ne le concernent pas. Par exemple:

> Mêle-toi de tes ognons ! -> Occupe-toi de ce qui te concerne !
>
> Je déteste quand ma mère se mêle de ma vie sentimentale
>
> Depuis que l'inspecteur s'en mêle, l'affaire n'avance plus.

On remarque qu'il n'y a plus vraiment le sens de mélange.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a de ça effectivement.

> Se mêler de quelque chose

N'est en théorie pas spécialement péjoratif, puisqu'on pourrait se mêler de ce qui nous regarde (comme avec "mêle-toi de ce qui te concerne"), mais est quasi-exclusivement utilisé dans un contexte où on se mêle de quelque chose qui ne nous regarde pas.

> Être mêlé à

Effectivement, 'être mêlé à' emporte l'idée d'être impliqué contre son gré dans une histoire/situation, mais surtout parce que c'est du passif.

> Se mêler à (une foule, aux autres etc.)

S'intégrer à/ participer, souvent en parlant de personnes, de groupes.